# Why Delphi XE 7 places component/events definitions in a wrong section?

Tags: delphi-xe7

I have annoying problem with my Delphi XE 7. When I place some component on a form or double click to generate some event i.e. OnCreate it is placed in a public declarations instead of class declaration.
Every time I get compilation errors. Then I have to look where it placed new declarations. Form definition is not too complicated. It worked fine in a Delphi 6.

Comment: Works fine here. What's different about your environment?

Comment: Put a 600 to 1000 public variables in public section and we'll see.

Comment: If you're foolish enough to *put 600 to 1000 public variables* anywhere, I'm not surprised you're having issues. Try writing better code that doesn't need all those public variables.

Comment: What if I have many controls, menus, buttons, labels etc? I'm stupid because I dont make hello world and that is it? Software that is created through the years can have some issues. But Everything was fine in delphi 6 I don't understand why xe 7 such great product does not work properly.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found solution: cut those 600 lines with public variables and copy them to external file *. inc and then incude it just after public keyword. Now Delphi xe 7 puts component decalations in a proper place.